# Is it possible to set a group policy (or similar) which kills certain processes between certain hours?

Tags: windows, group-policy, process

The title really says it all. We're running a windows network and there are some applications which benefit from being killed overnight, but we don't want to have to enforce a reboot to do that.

Is it possible to only kill certain processes with a group policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stock functionality in Group Policy doesn't give you a way to execute arbitrary code during Group Policy refresh. (You get "Startup Scripts", "Shutdown Scripts", "Logon Scripts", and "Logoff Scripts".)

You could use Group Policy to deploy a "Scheduled Task" (either through Software Installation Policy w/ a custom package or via a "Startup Script") that would do the killing that you're looking for. That's probably the best way to get your "automated kill" code out onto the machines that need it.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me the information I need to get further with this. I'm not a sysadmin, and delving into the capabilities of group policy wasn't something I had time for.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Even Anderson. We do something similar using scheduled tasks and PsTools.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649